# PC Wakes With Task Scheduler But Goes Back to Sleep 3 Minutes Later

Tags: sleep, power

I have an old HP Envy 17" laptop.

I have configured a task in Task Scheduler to wake this system up at 7:15 a.m. using `cmd.exe /c "exit"`.

This works perfectly and the machine wakes right up when it is supposed to. But approx. 3 minutes later, it goes back to sleep again. Any ideas on how I can keep it awake?

BTW, this machine's BIOS has no power on wake timer settings, so it is software or nothing.

Comment: Did you check what's defined on Power options?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 is by default configured to timeout and return to sleep two minutes
after a system unattended wake up, which is what you are seeing.

You may increase the time the computer stays awake by modifying the registry,
as follows.

Start `regedit` and navigate to the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0\DefaultPowerSchemeValues`.

You will see here three sub-keys:

```
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e    Balanced
8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c    High performance
a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a    Power saver
```

Click on the entry corresponding to your power plan and verify the settings
for the items
`ACSettingIndex` for when plugged-in and `DCSettingIndex` for when on battery.
The times are in units of seconds.

Both items will have by default the value of "0x00000078 (120)", for 120 seconds.
You may set it for higher values (or much higher values).
It may be that setting them to zero will disable them completely
(but I have never tried).

For more information and methods, see the article
[fix Windows sleep mode problem](https://www.geeksengine.com/article/fix-windows-sleep-mode.html).

If this doesn't work for some reason, see the article
[5 Tools to Prevent Windows From Sleeping or Turning Off the Display](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/dont-sleep-prevent-windows-from-standby-shutdown-hibernate-and-restart/).

Comment: Much thanks! The registry edits unfortunately did not work. I set both AC and DC to 3500 on all 3 power plans just to be sure. Still goes back to sleep after 2 minutes. So I followed the advice in your article about invoking my audio player and set it to play a long ambient piece. That does the trick!

Comment: There might be more economical tools for keeping Windows awake. I added a link to an article with 5 such tools.

Comment: Thanks for the extra suggestions! I'll give them a try.