# Task scheduler runs at delayed time during sleep

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

### EDIT 02/03/2023

The following is what I get from running `powercfg -energy` as suggested by one of the comments.

[image]

---

I have a task that is supposed to run at 2 am every day. However I face 2 issues:

1. It runs at some odd time after 2am but not at 2am.
2. If the program goes wrong, it gets shut down after a few hours, even though I have set it to shut down after running for 1 hour.

I am currently on a Windows 10 system, and the laptop is constantly plugged in, the tasks that are scheduled to run when I am using my laptop works perfectly fine. But this task runs when I am logged out and the computer is sleeping, not sure if this may be related to the erratic behaviour.

**Here is the history of the task execution:**
[image]
[image]

**Here are the settings of the task:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Sylvain the time difference is shown in the history under the screenshot. It is indeed a problem, else I would not be posting it here. If it failed and is being retried, it would have shown up in the history and recorded as such. Also 3 hours from 2:56am is 5:56am, so it still would not make sense.

Comment: In older Task schedulers there was an option "If the task does not end when requested, force it to stop". In short, without this option, the scheduler didn't force the kill if the application didn't comply to the terminate signal. On recent versions I don't know. But maybe your application can't be killed (doesn't comply, priviledges...)? And for the scheduled hour, no idea, sorry.

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1488917/8672) is related to the question, if the unattended wake up time is not enough, leading to consecutive attempts.

Comment: @tangolin check the windows system event logs for Kernel-Power and Power-Troubleshooter events. It should show events for every time the PC woke from sleep due to scheduled tasks, and you can determine whether the PC is attempting to wake for the task or doing something else weird like switching into Hibernate or Doze power states

Comment: Run also [powercfg -energy](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/topic/guided-help-get-a-detailed-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-for-your-computer-in-windows-7-3f6ce138-fc04-7648-089a-854bcf332810) and post online the result report.

Comment: The fact that one task started at 2:53 and ended at 6:56 indicates that the task failed 4 times (with a restart delay of 1 minute) after a timeout of 1 hour (total time: 4 hours and 3 minutes). So the task kept running for an hour and then restarted 3 times.
Do you have any logging setup in your "task" for any additional info?

Comment: @GChuf can I clarify what you mean by logging setup

Comment: @harrymc because it is my work laptop, somehow I am not able to run powercfg -energy from the command prompt, i will upload a screenshot when I get it to work

Comment: @tangolin: We will need the entire file generated by the energy report.

Comment: @harrymc Hi, the powercfg report has been added to the original question

Comment: Posting as an image makes it hard to read, but there doesn't seem to be anything serious in it, or that contradicts my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems like the wake task is terminates too soon to finish
its task. This is because by default Windows 10 is configured to
timeout and return to sleep two minutes after a system unattended
wake up.

Here is an extract from
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1488917/8672)
of mine:

> You may increase the time the computer stays awake by modifying the
> registry, as follows.
>
> Start `regedit` and navigate to the key
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0\DefaultPowerSchemeValues`.
>
> You will see here three sub-keys:
>
> ```
> 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  Balanced
> 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  High performance
> a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  Power saver
> ```
>
> Click on the entry corresponding to your power plan and verify the
> settings for the items `ACSettingIndex` for when plugged-in and
> `DCSettingIndex` for when on battery. The times are in units of
> seconds.
>
> Both items will have by default the value of "0x00000078 (120)", for
> 120 seconds. You may set it for higher values (or much higher values).
> It may be that setting them to zero will disable them completely (but
> I have never tried).
>
> For more information and methods, see the article [fix Windows sleep
> mode
> problem](https://www.geeksengine.com/article/fix-windows-sleep-mode.html).